# Removing .svc help screen

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

When navigating to a .svc, I get the following screen:

http://s13.postimage.org/va1l2tibp/Untitled_1.jpg

Is it possible to remove this screen? I can't find anything on google about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the metadata (mex) endpoint in your config. Review this [blog post](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/27/wcf-metadata/) to see how it is enabled to remove the elements needed to display the mex endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was disable `httpGetEnabled` and delete my mex endpoints.